# Angular - AnchorScolling delay

Tags: angular, angular-router, anchor-scroll

For a starter, I created a StackBlitz webcontainer [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-webcontainer-navbar-anchorscrolling).

I'm using a bootstrap navbar which pushes the content down by incrementing the padding on the `.content` div. The links inside the navbar point to anchors on the pages.

```html
<h1 class="text-center">Page 2</h1>
<h2 id="part-one">Part 1</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
<h2 id="part-two">Part 2</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
<h2 id="part-three">Part 3</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
```

When a link is clicked the angular `RouterModule` navigates to this specific heading tag. But since there is an ongoing animation on the navbar component, angular seems to be confused and doesn't know where to scroll to.

Is there a way to delay the anchor-scrolling, so that it starts after the navbar has collapsed? The [`ExtraOptions`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/router/src/router_config.ts#L174) doesn't seem to contain a setting to delay the navigation...

I also considered using a route-guard which returns a promise that resolves `true` after .4s, but that obviously doesn't work when navigation to an anchor on the same page.

### Modify

You can change the behavior by adding/removing the `[bsNavbarContent]` from the bottom `div` in the **app.component.html**

References:

- [`SlideUpDownAnimation`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-animations/src/lib/slide-up-down.animation.ts)

### Edit

Angular calls [`window.scrollTo`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/viewport_scroller.ts#L158), but this method doesn't allow you to pass a `duration` parameter. Sadly this method doesn't have a callback/Promise signature either. So we cannot possibly exactly know when the scrolling has finished.

[Here's](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3744#issuecomment-1610328661) an open issue which requests a W3 draft update to change `scrollTo` and `scrollIntoView` to a `Promise`, but it's already 5 years old.

The issue [contains a post](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/3744#issuecomment-1610328661) which suggests using an IntersectionObserver, but this won't work when the element is already in the viewport and the anchortag is clicked. ([Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mfafhv?file=index.html))

Comment: I'll probably need to implement a custum `ViewportScroller` which extends the [default one](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/src/viewport_scroller.ts#L67) and uses `setTimeout` to call the base method

Comment: [Probably good example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-viewport-scroller?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcustom-viewport-scroller.ts%3AL17)